# When parse one WebElement from given list this print all the list

Tags: html, scala, selenium

So i have `Drop Down List` and when the user type some text a suggestions option pop up and when get this options i have this `List` of `WebElement`:

```
<div class="class1">
<span class="class2" style="display: block;">
<div class="class3">
  <div style="white-space: normal;">
    <p>
      <span class="class4"></span>
        <strong>val1</strong>
        <a class="edit" href="bla bla">Edit</a>
        </p>
          <p>val2</p>
          <p>val3</p>
        <p>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Get the list:

```
  def getSuggerstionList(): Unit = {

    val suggestion: List[WebElement] = ...
    parse(suggestion(0))
  }
```

So after get all this list i want to parse the first element and get val1, val2, val3:

```
  def parse(webElement: WebElement): Unit = {

    val element = webElement.findElements(By.cssSelector("p"))
    element.foreach(x => println(x.getText))
  }
```

So here i got a very strange behaviour: after print this element (the first element in the list) this print all the elements inside my list and not only the first one, am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `val element = webElement.findElements(By.cssSelector("p"))` you assign list to `element`.

In `element.foreach(x => println(x.getText))` you iterate over that list and print the text of each WebElement in it.

To print only the first use index

```
println(element(0))
```

Or locate only one element in the first place

```
val element = webElement.findElement(By.cssSelector("p")) //note the speling of findElement - without 's'
println(element)
```

Comment: OK this printing only val1 and Edit, i want also val2 and val3 (please see my html example) and i cannot reach the both.

Comment: @davidhol Well, you complained you have all the elements printed not only the first one. Than what's wrong with what you had?

Comment: @davidhol You can save all the elements list with `webElement.findElements(By.cssSelector("p"))` and reach them by index like in my first solution. `element(0).getText` will give you `val1`, `element(1).getText` will give you `val2` etc.